# Titanium: hide views when layout=vertical

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, layout, titanium

A common problem in Titanium UI is hiding a view inside a vertical layout.

Suppose we have this:

```
<Alloy>
  <View id="wrapper" layout="vertical">
    <Label id="sometimes_visible" top="20" height="50">I can be visible o not</Label>
    <Label id="always_visible" top="20" height="50">I'm always visible</Label>
  </View>
</Alloy>
```

and you, for some reason, need to hide `sometimes_visible` label:

```
$.sometimes_visible.visible = false;
```

Maybe you're expecting the result to be:

```
_______________________________
|   ________________________   |
|   |  I'm always visible  |   |
|   ------------------------   |
|______________________________|
```

Instead, you are getting:

```
_______________________________
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|   ________________________   |
|   |  I'm always visible  |   |
|   ------------------------   |
|______________________________|
```

(unwanted space above the `always_visible` label)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because in Titanium, `visible=false` simply set the view invisible, but it still occupy its space. Thus, in vertical layout, other views don't rearrange in order to fill the gap (which is correct, even if unwanted).

A snippet to solve this is the following:

```
/**
 * hides a view nested into a layout=vertical container
 * acts on top, bottom and height to simulate html-style display:none
 * @param  {Ti.View} view the view to be hidden
 */
function hideVertical(view) {
    //store previous values
    view.__originalValues = {
        top: view.top,
        bottom: view.bottom,
        height: view.height
    };

    //set new values to simulate invisibility
    view.top = 0;
    view.bottom = 0;
    view.height = 0;
    view.visible = false;
}

/**
 * shows a view nested into a layout=vertical container
 * restore from hideVertical()
 * @param  {Ti.View} view the view to be shown
 */
function showVertical(view) {
    //restore previous values
    view = _.extend(view, view.__originalValues || {});

    view.visible = true;
}
```

It can be implemented in controller's code by simply:

```
hideVertical($.sometimes_visible);
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/balanza/c396ac1f5013fd586ce4)

Comment: or `$.wrapper.remove($.sometimes_visible);` will also do the trick

Comment: off course, but this would remove the view from the view tree (which I don't know if it's bad or not)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just:

```
$.view.height = 0;
```

It does exactly what you want without removing the view from the tree.